# data of api response is not logged in console

Tags: typescript, angular7

I am making an api call through which I am getting some json data back in response. I can see that data in developer tools but when i try to assign that response data in a class instance and log a particular key of it, it is showing undefined.

I also tried logging the response raw data into the console but that also shows undefined.

```
apicall.subscribe(
                (response) => {

                    // check response status
                    if (response.status === 'success') {
                        this.info =  response.data;
                        console.log(response.data);
                        console.log(this.info);
```

Comment: this.info is the object of a class which has another object as its attribute. adding the dummy json of info object. ```{
 name: 'hello world',
 address: {
   state: 'LA',
   country: 'us'
 }
}```